# how to order the bars in the order as they receive in matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

How to order the  bars in the  frequency plot in the order of 0,1,2,3,4 instead of the highest frequency as shown in the below picture?

[image]

This is the code i used:

```
train_df.Fedu.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.6)
plt.title("Distribution of Father's  education")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sort_index`:

```
train_df.Fedu.value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]